# Determining polynomial model coefficients forcing slope = 1 and intercept =0

Tags: regression, polynomial

I have two observational variables, $\text{C}_{\text{obs}}$ and $R$, both subject to measurement error. I believe that a model of the form $$\text{C}_{\text{mod}} = a_0 + a_1R + a_2R^2 + a_3R^3$$ would be a reasonable representation of the relationship between $\text{C}_{\text{obs}}$ and $R$.  I want to determine the coefficient vector $[a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3]$ in this model.  An often-cited reference in my field describes finding these parameters using a procedure that forces the slope and intercept of the linear relationship between $\text{C}_{\text{mod}}$ and $\text{C}_{\text{obs}}$ to be 1 and 0, but does not provide any details on the method.  I have attempted to contact the author directly without success, and I have been unable to find references to such a procedure (but I may not be using the correct search terms).  I am an IDL user and am familiar with R; I would appreciate it if someone could explain how to solve this problem or point me to IDL or R routines that might be applied.

Comment: What is this "often-cited reference"? It would also be helpful to describe (briefly) what the field of application is, and what Cobs, Cmod and R represent.